# Intrinsic value of non-voting shares which don't pay dividends

Tags: stock-valuation

What is the intrinsic value of a company's non-voting stock shares which don't pay dividends?

My understanding is stock ownership has value in the form of controlling the company or receiving a portion of the profits.  Where does value derive from when neither of these is present?

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: @Christian Google does not pay dividends, but last year it issued non-voting shares.  According to [this article](http://www.thestreet.com/story/12626731/1/google-slumps-after-founders-issue-non-voting-shares.html), there is a clause where google is obligated to somehow "pay the difference" between voting and non-voting shares if the public stops perceiving the value in non-voting shares.  The article cites Facebook and LInkedIn as other examples.

Comment: What about the potential of future dividends? A lot of companies in their early stages don't have dividends yet people will buy the stock on hope.

Comment: To have equity in the enterprise at the moment of future events.  The existence or non-existence of dividends in this moment do not bind the future to be the same.  Also, in the event the enterprise is merged into another one, or spins off a division, equity participates in proportion to equity.

Comment: @JBKing this was my thought as well.  Maybe the only possible way to value such shares is the **hope** that the company will someday start paying out cash.   I would consider Google a mature company, but they still don't pay dividends.

Comment: @user662852 could you please make this into an answer below and explain your comment more?

Comment: Note that there is another way to get money to stockholders.  The company can buy back some of its stock.  This is most common in cash rich companies with grumbling stockholders (due, for instance, to falling stock values).

Comment: Google is clearly large enough to begin paying out dividends, but the founders have expressed that they don't really intend to do so in the future. Instead they've been throwing money at R&D and not really generating a profit. Furthermore, when companies liquidate nowadays, they usually are straddled in debt and have nothing left for common stock holders. Most companies are not going to liquidate themselves when they can clearly survive.

Comment: To me the high price of Goog stock is clearly operating off of the greater fool theory like bitcoin.

Comment: At least the supply of crypto currency is limited!  Goog stock can be created at any time for any reason.

Answer (score 4):

Even with non-voting shares, you own a portion of the company including all of its assets and its future profits.  If the company is sold, goes out of business and liquidates, etc., those with non-voting shares still stand collect their share of the funds generated.  There's also the possibility, as one of the comments notes, that a company will pay dividends in the future and distribute its assets to shareholders that way.

The example of Google (also mentioned in the comments) is interesting because when they went to voting and non-voting stock, there was some theoretical debate about whether the two types of shares (GOOG and GOOGL) would track each other in value.  It turned out that they did not - People did put a premium on voting, so that is worth something.  Even without the voting rights, however, Google has massive assets and each share (GOOG and GOOGL) represented ownership of a fraction of those assets and that kept them highly correlated in value.

(Google had to pay restitution to some shareholders of the non-voting stock as a result of the deviation in value. I won't get into the details here since it's a bit of tangent, but you could easily find details on the web.)

Answer (score 0):

Some companies offer discounts for shareholders. I believe Disney used to do so, for example; if your family was doing the Disneyland-every-year routine that could be a significant benefit.

Comment: I don't think most people buy stock in a company to get discounts on the company's products.  I would fire a financial adviser if he told me this rational.

Comment: The question was whether there was any intrinsic value, not whether there was investment value.

Comment: This [definition from Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/intrinsicvalue.asp) and this [definition from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_value_(finance)) both focus on things like "business model, governance, financial ratios, and financial statement analysis" in their definition of intrinsic value.  Furthermore, the question was "What is the intrinsic value" not "Is there any intrinsic value", which is different.

Comment: This is famously a way to save thousands on cruises and Ford cars.

Comment: @steampowered: The word, and the question as written, admit of multiple meaning. If that's the specific one you want, clarify the question.